# java delete reverse string in list

Tags: java, string, algorithm, reverse

I have struct  Array or List String like:

```
{ "A.B", "B.A", "A.C", "C.A" }
```

and I want delete reverse string from list that end of only:

```
{ "A.B", "A.C" }
```

how type String use and how delete reverse String?

Comment: You'd have to define *exactly* what you mean by "reverse string" here. Would `{ "B.A", "C.A" }` be another acceptable answer, for example?

Comment: what should be the output if list is { "B.A", "A.B", "C.A", "A.C" }.. Should the answer must be {"B.A", "C.A"}

Comment: my reverse that "A.C" and "C.A". Need leave only "A.C" or "C.A"

Answer (score 0):

To reverse a string I recommend using a StringBuffer.

```
String sample = "ABC";
String reversed_sample = new StringBuffer(sample).reverse().toString();
```

To delete object form you ArrayList use the remove method.

```
String sample = "ABC";String to_remove = "ADS";
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<Sample>();
list.add(to_remove);list.add(sample );
list.remove(to_remove);
```

Comment: Why StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder?

Comment: Or even better a StringBuilder: your variable is local so there clearly is no concurrency issue here.

Comment: in mya samle String number format "1.0.10.2" and "2.10.0.1" StringBuffer revers no

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very simply in `O(n^2)` time. Psuedocode:

```
For every element1 in the list:
     For every element2 in the list after element1:
         if reverse(element2).equals(element1)
             list.remove(element2)
```

In order to make your life easier and prevent ConcurrentModificationException use `Iterator`. I won't give you the code because it's a good example to learn how to properly use iterators in Java.

Reverse method:

```
public String reverse(String toReverse) {
    return new StringBuilder(toReverse).reverse().toString();
}
```

Edit: another reverse method:

```
public String reverse(String toReverse) {
     if (toReverse != null && !toReverse.isEmpty) {
         String[] elems = toReverse.split(".");
     }
     StringBuilder reversedString = new StringBuilder("");
     for (int i = elems.length - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
          reversedString.append(elems[i]);
          reversedString.append(".");
     }
     return reversedString.toString();
}
```

Comment: i need reverse number string that "10.0.0.20" was "20.0.0.10" and not standart reverse "02.0.0.01"

Comment: That was not said in your question.

Comment: Being honest I don't get why someone voted down my answer... it's always better for a person who asks a question to get an advice how to implement something and why instead of getting simply the ready code

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the list while maintaining a `Set<String>` of elements in it.

While you do it - create a new list (which will be the output) and:

```
   if (!set.contains(current.reverse())) {
       outputList.append(current)
       set.add(current)
   }
```

This solution is `O(n*|S|)` on average, where `n` is the number of elements and `|S|` is the average string length.

**Java Code:**

```
private static String reverse(String s) { 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = s.length()-1 ; i >=0 ; i--) { 
        sb.append(s.charAt(i));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
private static List<String> removeReverses(List<String> arr) { 
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String s : arr) { 
        if (!set.contains(reverse(s))) {
            res.add(s);
            set.add(s);
        }
    }
    return res;
}
public static void main(String[]args){
    String[] arr = { "a.c" , "b.c", "c.a", "c.b" };
    System.out.println(removeReverses(arr));
}
```

will yield:

```
[a.c, b.c]
```

Comment: @amit:The `!set.contains{..}` is unneeded.You simply can do: `if (set.add(reverse(s))) {  
     res.add(s);    
}`

Comment: @Cratylus: partially, by doing if `(set.add(...)) { ... }` you neglect duplicate elements. The question doesn't mention it, but I assumed `{"a.c", "c.a", "c.a", "a.c"}` for example should yield `{"c.a","c.a"}` or `{"a.c","a.c"}`. Of course if it is not the case - you are correct.

Comment: @amit:Also for the reverse:just do: `return new StringBuilder(s).reverse();`

Comment: @amit:The code you posted is equivalent to my comment.You check if `reverse(s)` is contained and if not then you add it in `res` and `set`.In my suggestion `set.add` will return `false` if it already exists so the result is the same with your code but you skipped an extra iteration for `contains`

Comment: @Cratylus: Just tried it, the `add()` comment doesn't work (for the original input). Note that in each iteration we add `s`, while we check if the set contains `reverse(s)`.

Comment: @amit can you change removeReverses(String[] arr)  to removeReverses(List<String> arr)  ?

Comment: @basvas: Ok. Note that it is identical except the signature. You can also invoke the array version with `removeReverses(list.toArray(new String[0]))` (where `list` is your `List<String>`). I

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
    String str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";


    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    strList.add("A.B");
    strList.add("B.A");
    strList.add("A.C");
    strList.add("C.A");

    Iterator<String> itr = strList.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
        String [] split = itr.next().toUpperCase().split("\\.");

        if(str.indexOf(split[0])>str.indexOf(split[1])){
            itr.remove();
        }
    }

     System.out.println(strList);


}
```

output is

```
[A.B, A.C]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get use of a `HashMap` to determine whether a string is a reversed version of the other strings in the list. And you will also need a utility function for reversing a given string. Take a look at this snippets:

```
String[] input = { "A.B", "B.A", "A.C", "C.A" };
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] output = new String[input.length];
int index = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if (!map.containsKey(input[i])) {
        map.put(reverse(input[i]), "default");
        output[index++] = input[i];
    }
}
```

A sample String-reversing method could be like this:

```
public static String reverse(String str) {
    String output = "";
    int size = str.length();
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        output += str.charAt(i) + "";
    return output;
}
```

**Output:**
The output array will contain these elements => `[A.B, A.C, null, null]`

Answer (score 0):

A code is worth thousand words.....

```
public class Tes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
        arr.add("A.B");
        arr.add("B.A");
        arr.add("A.C");
        arr.add("C.A");

        System.out.println(arr);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {

            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(arr.get(i));

            String revStr = str.reverse().toString();

            if (arr.contains(revStr)) {

                arr.remove(i);

            }
        }

        System.out.println(arr);

    }

}
```

Comment: Note that the solution is `O(n^2 * |S|)`, as `contains()` is `O(n)` itself for `ArrayList`.